# Virtual Host on centos

Tags: centos, virtualhost, testing

I started virtual host on my VPS,

I am having two websites on it, one which was already there and the second which I trasferred now,
But before changing the name-servers of the new transfered wordpress site, I want to test it.
How can I check it, whether its working with no errors, or some errors are there?

When I type my IP address of the VPS I get my old website, if I type http://ip/new_site_folder_name I get 404, no such page found

My virtual host config is this:

```
    NameVirtualHost *:80
    <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/www.mbas.co.in
    ServerName mbas.co.in
    ErrorLog logs/mbas.co.in-error_log
    CustomLog logs/mbas.co.in-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/onlinemba123
    ServerName onlinemba123
    ErrorLog logs/onlinemba123-error_log
    CustomLog logs/onlinemba123-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: If you use the IP addy, you'll always get the first vhost Apache is configured for; your second vhost has an *interesting* hostname, you're entering `http://onlinemba123` into your browser and have that exact hostname mapped in your hosts file?

Comment: @Chris S so in ServerName I have to change from onlinemba123 to http://onlinemba123
Am I rite?

Comment: ServerName should be exactly what you enter into the address bar *after* `http://` and *before* `/whatever/page.html`.

Comment: @Chris S I enter exactly same, but one more thing, do I have to set DNS settings?, cause I haven't till yet

Comment: @Ntechi, you don't have to change DNS. There must be something else in your configuration file that's messing this up. What you have above is syntactically correct.

Comment: @Chris S then why am I getting Centos Default page instead of my website, where as my other website is working fine

Comment: If neither of those directories have the default page in them, someone else in the configuration file is hosed. ;)

Comment: @Chris S so what should I do now?

Comment: Start looking over the rest of the configuration file(s). I'm not good with CentOS, so I'm not sure how many files there are or where they're located, but most Linux distros have Apache divided up into several sections.

Comment: @Chris S no any other solution rather then this?
OK I ll see to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've already changed your DNS, which is fine. But I wanted to mention that if you want to test your virtual host configuration before messing with the DNS settings (useful if you want to keep an old site live while you get everything ready on the new host) you can temporarily make the change in your [hosts file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29) on your local computer and the change will take effect immediately.

Comment: in hosts file, what IP should I write 127.0.0.1 or the current VPS IP?

Comment: On the computer your testing from (the workstation you're sitting at) edit the hosts files and put in `[ip_of_server] old_site.co.in`. Test (with a browser on your computer). Then remove the line.

Comment: @Chris S, I tried that, when I enter in URL, then my old site is opening, instead of the new one, why so

Comment: Correcting your configuration is outside the scope of the original question. This isn't a forum for ongoing discussions. From the Apache documentation "the argument to VirtualHost must match the argument to NameVirtualHost"

Comment: @Chris S I didn't get you,
Is there anything wrong with my virtual host config?

Comment: @ntechi yes your config is slightly off. Apache doesn't know how to get to the new site which is why it defaulting to the old. The VirtualHost tags should be the same for both and should be bound to *:80. Like this <VirtualHost *:80>

Comment: @mathew I did as per your saying, but now when I type new_website on url, I am getting the default "Apache 2 Test Page" , and my old website is working well, now my config is changed, check my question

Comment: I think we're beyond the scope of the original question.Based on what I see of your config if you use onlinemba123 as the domain in your url you'll get to the second virtual host. If you use any other domain you'll get to first virtual host.  However if you are getting somewhere else it means there's some other part of your config that's taking over.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the form http://new_site.co.in, the folder name is irrelevant because it will become the root folder of your site.

Edit - Explanation of vhosts

Based on your comments, I don't think you understand how virtual hosts in Apache work.

First, both domains (old_site.co.in and new_site.co.in) must point to the IP of your machine (this is a DNS thing). With the site definitions your wrote in your post, you will then tell apache to serve the contents of /html/www.old_site.co.in when a browser tries to open http://www.old_site.co.in and the contents of /html/www.new_site.co.in if the browser asks for http://www.new_site.co.in. This works even if both domains have the same IP address because the site name is transferred in the HTTP request.

Comment: I agree.  The  http://ip/new_site_folder_name  scheme is not a function of apache.  It's frequently part of some control panel software (such as Plesk, or cPanel), but it does not exist on a default apache installation on CentOS.

Comment: but my folder name is same as my domain name, which is pointing somewhere, so that website will open, any other way?
And if I change the folder name, and then type on url http://new_site.com, will it get opened? I think their will be no such site with this name, so it will return 404

Comment: Why don't you just try it? Also, see my edit for an explanation of how this works.

Comment: OK in my DNS, I have added everything, and I also changed the folder name, but now when I type new_named_site, I get server not found

Comment: This might be because DNS entries might take a while before propagating. Try the command `nslookup new_site.co.in` to see if your DNS entry is correct.

Comment: I am getting this, when I typed nslookup
`Server:         89.36.21.42
Address:        89.36.21.42#53

** server can't find onlinemba123: NXDOMAIN
`

Comment: Because `onlinemba123` is not a valid domain name without a TLD suffix (like .com, .org or .co.uk).